# show data from database in table format inside form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have an input form connected to a database.
After [the form is submitted], I want to make a form to show all the data which has been input to the database. I want to show this data in table sortable by name or date.

Please help me.

Comment: what is exactly the question?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. Where exactly are you stucking while writing code? Are you able to do a PHP hello world? MySQL hello world? Connect MySQL in PHP? Write SQL queries? Get data from MySQL in PHP? Show data in PHP? Create a HTML table? Create a HTML form? Let PHP intercept on POST data? Etcetera. One could write a book about this. No way that you get all pages of that book here ;) Tell, what do you have as far and what's the missing piece in the puzzle? Or don't you even know where to start?

Comment: @artefacto: 
first..i'm already make an input form and all data succesfully insert to database..

second..i want make an information form which is content of all data who have been input to database..but it can show in table format

Comment: @balusC:
i don't even know where to start..

Comment: exactly i want get a data from database then show it as table format

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear what the problem is. The **question** is missing. Here are some examples of questions: "How do I retrieve data from a MySQL database?", "How do I create a HTML table?" (note that they usually start with "How" and end with a question mark).

Comment: i mean..How do I retrieve data from a MySQL database then show that data inside html table? isn't it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high-level steps you want to take are:

1. Print HTML table header
2. Establish a connection to the database
3. Issue a query, and capture the result (e.g. as an array)
4. Loop through the array, printing each HTML table row
5. Clean up database objects that may be holding onto memory or db connections
6. Print HTML table close

The following example is a slightly modified version of example #2 from [this page on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). I suggest you spend a lot of time on that site - the manual is excellent, and almost every page has numerous working examples in the comments section.

```
<table>
<?php
// Establish the database connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

// Issue the query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

// Capture the result in an array, and loop through the array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    // Print each row as HTML: <tr><td>row 0</td><td>row 1</td>
    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
// Free the result set    
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</table>
```